# Are there any canadian institutions backing bitcoin?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, canada

I'd love to know if there are.

Comment: I strongly doubt any state institution is doing such a thing.

Comment: Can you clarify your definition of "institutions"?

Comment: Can you also clarify what you mean by "backing", given that Bitcoin is decentralised?

Comment: @HighlyIrregular well, "backing" could mean "they accept _vel_ give Bitcoins as payments"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very short answer is simply no. Generally governments ignore bitcoin for now.

Answer (score 0):

No major banks are "backing" Bitcoin. Some have been hostile towards Bitcoin, while some have remained neutral.

Reference: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=264679.0